# How do I connect and run SQL codes in an ASP with MS SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp-classic

I am trying to connect to an MS SQL Server with an classic ASP file and run a SQL query that gives the output in the ASP file. I am using MS SQL Server 2008 and windows aunthentication. I read many articles and went through questions and answers but nothing seems to help.

I use the following connection to connect to MS SQL server but it does not want to connect.

```
Dim con

Set con = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

con.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=DemoDB;Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS"


con.Close
Set con = Nothing
```

If I use

```
Dim con

    Set con = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

    con.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS"

    con.Close
    Set con = Nothing
```

it connects to the server but i can't seem to run a SQL code. The code i tried to run  with the SQL code included looks like this:

```
<%

Dim con
Dim rs

Set con = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = Sever.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

con.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS"
rs.Open "USE DemoDB SELECT * FROM data", con

rs.MoveFirst
Response.Write(rs.Fields(0).Value)

con.Close
Set con = Nothing

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing

%>
```

Can somoene please point out what I am doing wrong in my code. I keep getting the following error message:

> An error occurred on the server when processing the URL. Please
>   contact the system administrator.  If you are the system administrator
>   please click here to find out more about this error.

Comment: Is the account you are using to run ASP an allowed account for the server? Task manager should tell you the user account name. That user account must have permission in SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

You don't need USE if the demo DB is already specified in the connection string.

```
' see end of this line ---->
con.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=demoDB"

rs.Open "SELECT * FROM data", con
```

Should work in that case.

However if it isn't use this

```
rs.Open "USE demoDB; SELECT * FROM data", con
```

But the first method is preferred.